# Jest Test React Router Link navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, react-router-dom, enzyme

I have the following component that I want to test using Jest Enzyme.

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
      <Route path='/' component={Home}/>
      <Route path='/view' component={View}/>
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>

class Home extends React.Component {
    render {
      <Link to='/view'>
         <button onClick={() => foo}>View Data</button>
      </Link>
    }
}
```

This code is working in application correctly.
However, when I test button click using jest-enzyme, component path or content doesn't change

```
it('should redirect on button click', () => {
   const component= mount(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={{['/', '/view']}}>
         <Route path='/' component={Home}/>
         <Route path='/view' component={View}/>
      </MemoryRouter>
   )

   expect(component.find('Home')).toHaveLength(1); //passes
   expect(component.find('LinkAnchor').props().href).toEqual('/view'); //this also passes
   component.find('button').simulate('click');
   expect(component.find('View').toHaveLength(1); //This FAILS
});
```

My question:

1. Is only way to test Link could be checking href in it's internal a tag?
2. Can we test page navigation like it works properly for ?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you probably want to test the history object of the `MemoryRouter` to be updated when you have clicked the link.

However, you are running into this problem because you're wrapping a button with a link and you are pressing the button *not* the link.

If you need button styling for your links, you should update the `Link` component instead:

```
return (
  <Link to='/view' className='buttonClass' onClick={() => foo()} />
);
```

Comment: My history location also doesn't change. I have tried this also.

Comment: Have you tried the example from the [react router documentation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing/checking-location-in-tests)?

Comment: Thanks for the reference link. The example provided is working because it uses react-dom render in test. I need to use mount as I am writing integration test involving react lifecycle methods and redux store. So, I used mount with attach to a div and rendered it at required time. Now I get navigation not defined error. Meaning, at-least now it tries to navigate.